# Scripting Language that can count number of files and do simple plotting

Tags: excel, windows

I am looking for a programming language that can do the following:

1. Count the number of files (User will specify the file type and date range) in a directory.
2. Windows-based
3. Can do simple GUI that will prompt the user with input values
4. Can do simple plotting of bar and line graphs
5. Can take input values from an Excel file.
6. Can do simple means test like t-test or ANOVA.

The purpose is this. I need to automize the weekly sample per consumable ratio data. Every picture file corresponds to one sample tested. The consummable data is logged in an excel file. So the program I want to write will "read" the number of samples tested by counting the picture files. And it will "read" the consummable used by reading the Excel file.

Input is as follows:
1. Date range where you want to see the sample tested per consummable ratio
2. Machine number and consummable type to know which part of Excel file to extract
3. Tick bar as option if we want to do stat test or not.

Output:
1. Bar or line graph (sample tested per consummable ratio vs time)
2. T-test results if we want to do a comparison of two time periods.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Language? Your question is about few algorithms need to be written, in almost EVERY script language. Writing GUI or Office is quite sophisticated. Do You use any programming language?

Comment: Hm, okay, I've written very basic scripts on VBA (at Excel), Fortran, Bash, and JSL (using JMP). I'm not really a programmer; I just automize my repetitive tasks such as summarizing txt files to one dataset. So you mean to say that I can count the number of files in a directory using any langunage?

Comment: why did You not use VBA? Maybe in slight changed scenario. With other languages learning time will be significant - Your goal is ambitious